# How to display money values with Prawn in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, prawn, prawnto

I am using [Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com) to generate a PDF with a table and various money values in it.

Everything looks fine when using dollars or pounds since the currency symbols are preceding the money values. All the values are neatly aligned to the right as expected.

[image: Correct]

Once I switch to euros, though, the appended euro signs appear outside their respective cells, like hanging in the air.

[image: Wrong]

This is the simple helper function I am using to display prices in my Prawn documents:

```
def price(num)
  @view.number_to_currency(num)
end
```

This is the method to generate the `line_items`:

```
def line_items
  move_down 30   
  table line_item_rows do
    row(0).font_style = :bold
    row(0).size = 8
    row(-1).font_style = :bold
    cells.borders = [:bottom]
    cells.padding = [5, 0, 5, 0]
    cells.border_color = "000000"
    columns(2..5).align = :right
    column(0).width = 80
    column(2).width = 50
    column(3).width = 70
    column(4).width = 60
    column(5).width = 70 
    self.header = true
  end
end
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your code? It seems alignment problem.You want to adjust `:at=>[row,column]` value.  For example

```
pdf.draw_text "Amount : #{order.amount}", :size => 9, :at => [10,308]
```

Comment: Hello & thanks for your help. I added my `line_items` method above. I am using a table to build them. Would you recommend to use `draw_text` instead?

Comment: Hi.I think Your coding is right.You can also do by that way.Can you check your Database value or what you display here. Because for dollars or pounds Preis = 100.00(dot) but euros= 100,00(comma) My guess is, you might fetch values as 100,00 € So Its displaying values as it is.

Comment: Hi. No, the prices are stored as decimals in the database and the total is simply calculated by multiplying prices and quantities. I am using all those values in many other places of my application as well and they are neatly aligned everywhere. It must be an issue specific to Prawn.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem with `prawn 1.0.0.rc2` . It worked fine with `1.0.0.rc1` so meanwhile I downgraded to `1.0.0.rc1`.

If you are able to do this I suggest to downgrade too.

Hope this help

**Edit**:

I opened an issue on github about it: https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/499

Comment: Thanks for your help! I downgraded to `1.0.0.rc1` as well but the error is still there. Anything else you did to fix it?

Comment: Nothing else, and it works for me. Just in case, did you run your server with `bundle exec`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi probably too late but i had similiar problem with rails 4 and this worked for me
`<span class= "price"> <%= number_to_currency(product.price, :unit => "€") %></span>`

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Prawn that was fixed in version 0.13.1.

Upgrading should solve the problem for you, but bear in mind that if you're coming from 0.12.0 or earlier a lot has changed. The differences between 0.13 and the current release (0.14) are much smaller.